# ls command works but not with options?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, shell, busybox

In my terminal app when I type `ls /?` it gives me `ls /d`. Where can I find the other options?  For example I want  to list the file attributes  and file length.  I have tried also busybox to no avail.

Comment: The `/?` is a Windows/DOS thing. It generally has no meaning under Linux/Unix. If `ls` on Android provides a help page it's probably `ls --help` (as it is on a desktop Linux distro).

Comment: This I have also tried to no avail?

Comment: It might be helpful to include your phone model / ROM and list the output of `busybox ls --help`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want the extremely common

```
ls -l
```

For reference, the complete busybox help for ls:

```
BusyBox v1.21.0-Stericson (2013-01-28 21:49:55 GMT) multi-call binary.

Usage: ls [-1AaCxdLHRFplinsehrSXvctu] [-w WIDTH] [FILE]...

List directory contents

        -1      One column output
        -a      Include entries which start with .
        -A      Like -a, but exclude . and ..
        -C      List by columns
        -x      List by lines
        -d      List directory entries instead of contents
        -L      Follow symlinks
        -H      Follow symlinks on command line
        -R      Recurse
        -p      Append / to dir entries
        -F      Append indicator (one of */=@|) to entries
        -l      Long listing format
        -i      List inode numbers
        -n      List numeric UIDs and GIDs instead of names
        -s      List allocated blocks
        -e      List full date and time
        -h      List sizes in human readable format (1K 243M 2G)
        -r      Sort in reverse order
        -S      Sort by size
        -X      Sort by extension
        -v      Sort by version
        -c      With -l: sort by ctime
        -t      With -l: sort by mtime
        -u      With -l: sort by atime
        -w N    Assume the terminal is N columns wide
        --color[={always,never,auto}]   Control coloring
```

Comment: Solved! It was 2 ls installed and I deleted the one linked to toolbox. But what is toolbox?

Comment: Probably it is the phone vendor's custom version of busybox. Or it could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

I would generally not expect `/?` to provide meaningful output, because it's really a DOS/Windows thing. Linux/Unix command option are typically passed with hyphens, either a single one for short flags (for example, `ls -l`) or two hyphens for verbose ones (e.g. `--help`). Two possibilities that you can try:

1. If you're using a version provided by `busybox`, you can use `busybox ls --help`. Doing this without the call to `busybox` at the front of the command may not yield any results (e.g. CyanogenMod just responds with `unknown option '--'` if I try `ls --help`).
2. The Linux [man page for `ls`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) is readily available online. The options there are probably not all implemented in the Android binary, but it will give you a bit of an overview. You can also check the [man page for `busybox`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/busybox), which has all of the commands it implements as well as the options they support. I am not sure if the Android version implements all the same commands/options, but it very well may.

Comment: I tried with and without  busybox to no avail.

Comment: The help can be omitted from a `busybox` build. When omitted, you can't get help/usage information from busybox commands.